# word for a person who achieves the impossible

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Single word for a person who achieves the impossible.

Comment: [Miracle-worker](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22miracle-worker%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is pretty common in this context.

Comment: I think FumbleFingers has made a good suggestion. The concept is self-contradictory of course: if something can be achieved it is not impossible.

Comment: Genius ....????

Comment: Mr. Improbable?

Comment: Superman..............

Comment: [Supernatural](https://www.google.com/search?q=supernatural&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=supernatural+definition) comes to mind... do you have an example?

Answer (score 2):

Since the *impossible* has been accomplished, we must be talking about supernatural. Thus, the person is a *practitioner of magic*. There are many names that can be applied: ***magician***, ***wizard***, ***witch***, ***mystic***, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A  [prodigy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prodigy):

> - A person with exceptional talents or powers: a math prodigy.

American Heritage Dictionary

Comment: A prodigy is, however, mainly associated with children or, at best, youthful people, such as WA Mozart, F Mendelssohn or EW Korngold who were considered prodigies before they reached maturity, but not after.

Comment: @JoostKiefte - it is often used in that context, but is also used to refer to people who make incredible achievements.

Comment: Which is why I used 'mainly' instead of 'exclusively'....

Answer (score 1):

Although perhaps not 'the impossible,' [a rainmaker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rainmaker) "is known [figuratively] for achieving excellent results in a profession or field" and literally for being "capable of producing rain." (the Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

**Phenomenal** (adj)

> From a Greek root meaning "appearance," phenomenal describes something
>   so awesome and ***borderline miraculous*** it really has to actually
>   be seen to be believed.

- It's typically used to give positive praise to any person, event or
  item that seems **to transcend the norm.**

(vocabulary.com)

Answer (score 0):

A word for a person who achieves the impossible:

> **a dragonslayer**

Here are two other options:

- David (from David and Goliath)
- a phenom

If you're interested in adjectives, here are four:

- supernatural
- superhuman
- phenomenal
- miraculous